# Append a new column using the name of dataframe from list of dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr

Given a list of dataframes `l` as follows:

```
l <- list(a = data.frame(a_1 = c(11, 12),
                        a_2 = c(13, 14)),
          b = data.frame(b_1 = c(21, 22),
                        b_2 = c(23, 24)),
          c = data.frame(c_1 = c(31, 32),
                          c_2 = c(33, 34)))
print(l)
```

Out:

[image]

Now I would like to append a new column `new_col` using the name of each dataframe:

```
l[['a']]$new_col = 'a'
l[['b']]$new_col = 'b'
l[['c']]$new_col = 'c'
```

I wonder how to append column for each dataframe by using `names(l)` which is `[1] "a" "b" "c"` automatically? Thanks.

The final result will like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Method 1: tidyverse solution with map2

```
library(tidyverse)
map2(l, names(l), ~ mutate(.x, new_col = .y))
```

Output:

```
$a
  a_1 a_2 new_col
1  11  13       a
2  12  14       a

$b
  b_1 b_2 new_col
1  21  23       b
2  22  24       b

$c
  c_1 c_2 new_col
1  31  33       c
2  32  34       c
```

### Method 2: for loop solution

(`l` gives the above output):

```
for(i in 1:length(names(l))) {
  l[[i]]$new_col <- names(l)[i]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is it possible to using for loop such as `for(i in l) {...}`?

Comment: @ahbon absolutely: just edited my answer to add a for loop solution. `map2` does the same thing and is cleaner in my opinion, but use whichever you like.

Answer (score 2):

Or with `mapply()`:

```
mapply(cbind, l, "new_col"=names(l), SIMPLIFY=F)
```